# Simple Accordion Issue

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have this accordion issue where if the parent menu has NO "ul" just follow the link, but it doesn't seem work:

http://jsfiddle.net/avdQx/

```
$('ul#sidenav a.parent').click(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('fast', function () {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        });
    } else {
        if ($(this).parents('li').has('ul')) {
            $('ul#sidenav li.active ul').slideUp('fast', function () {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            });
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('fast', function () {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
            });
        } else {
            alert(1);
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example, I changed the second if condition to check if the currently clicked .parent element have ul in its parent :

```
$('ul#sidenav a.parent').click(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('fast', function () {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        });
    } else {
        if ( $('ul', $(this).parent() ).length>0 ) {
            $('ul#sidenav li.active ul').slideUp('fast', function () {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            });
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('fast', function () {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
            });
        } else {
            alert(1);
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/avdQx/1/

Comment: Thanks! :D Don't know what I'd do without SO